# Max(If( equivalent in DAX PowerPivot

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerpivot

This question has been asked and answered before, however the solutions I've found don't seem to work for my current situation.

My table looks like:

[image]

I want to return the highest value in column B for all instances of it's match in column A in power pivot.

With a standard excel function, I would use `=max(if(a2=a:a,b:b))` in column C.

I've tried `=CALCULATE(max(Table1[B]),filter(Table1,Table1[A]=Table1[A]))` but this is the result

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table1[A]` always equals `Table1[A]` so your condition is always true and thus doesn't do any meaningful filtering.

What you're looking for is to filter by the [earlier](https://dax.guide/earlier/) row context (from the original table, not the FILTER iterator function):

```
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Table1[B] ),
    FILTER ( Table1, Table1[A] = EARLIER ( Table1[A] ) )
)
```

Another way to do this is to use a variable to grab the row context before you're inside of the FILTER.

```
VAR CurrRowA = Table1[A]
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( Table1[B] ), Table1[A] = CurrRowA )
```